# Safari's support of calc() with viewport units?

Tags: css, safari, viewport-units

According to http://caniuse.com/viewport-units the current version of Safari should have full support of Viewport unitys. Yet when I use the code below:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(100vh - 90px);
    left: 0;
}
```

Safari doesn't understand it and defaults to `top: 0` (same thing on iOS Safari). In this particular instance I could use percentages I guess, but there are other instances where I've been forced to add some jQuery just for Safari, and that's something I find ugly.

**Why does Safari not understand the above for PC & iPhone despite caniuse.com telling me it has full support of viewport units? Is javascript the only alternative in some cases?**

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is still an issue in Safari when combining `calc()` and viewport units. A workaround you could use:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100vh;
    margin-top: -90px;
    left: 0;
}
```